# Circle animation not centered on center

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a little problem with the animation css of my circle.

The center of the animation is not displayed correctly where I click.

The translation(-50%, -50%) works only after the animation.

Here is a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/0UMwaZgBmiXWlU61EE2m

Do you have an idea how to deal with that?

```js
// Code goes here

function printMousePos(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("body");
  var para1 = document.createElement("div");
  para1.className = "circle";
  para1.setAttribute("style", "position : absolute;left:" + event.clientX + "px;top:" + event.clientY + "px");
  element.appendChild(para1);
  var para2 = document.createElement("div");
  para2.className = "point";
  para2.setAttribute("style", "position : absolute;left:" + event.clientX + "px;top:" + event.clientY + "px");

  element.appendChild(para2);
  console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY);
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
}

@keyframes circle {
  from {
    transform: scale(0, 0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(2, 2)
  }
}

.circle {
  color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation-name: circle;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
  /*transform-origin: 0 0;*/
}

.point {
  color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <h1>Click Everywhere</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your keyframes callout should look like this:

```
@keyframes circle {
  from {
    transform: scale(0,0) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(2,2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To begin the outer blue circle animation centered on the red dot, you need to transform the origin to its center. Each time in the key frame animation when you use `transform: scale(0,0);` or `transform: scale(2,2);` the center again transforms to its default top corner.

To fix this change these parts

```
.circle {
      transform-origin: center;
}
```

and

```
 @keyframes circle {
    from {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2,2);
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: So this is centered, thanks, but with: transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0,0); the animation disappeared on chrome

Comment: My bad! You are right definitively! 
I was writing: transform: translate(-50%, -50%) transform:  scale(2,2);

Comment: Oh, that's okay. Glad i could help!